# ASP.NET MVC dropdown with a empty option line

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_No)      
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee_No,
                        new SelectList(ViewBag.EmployeeList, "Value", "Text"),
                        "Choose Employee",
                        new { @class = "ui selecetion dropdown" })
```

I want it to write a blank line but it doesn't come up. Instead of an empty line, it writes in dropdown, but I can't select it as a line.

Comment: In your employeeList can you not just add a new value (I'm presuming first) that has a value of `String.Empty()`?

Comment: I try but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
"Choose Employee",
```

with an empty line

```
""
```